# VBA: Get table headers and contents and display output to a file

Tags: vba

I have a table like this:

```
            Name    Color   Shape   Size    Cost    Note 1  Note 2
Ctrl But A  Fruit 1   a     d        f       1       6        9
Ctrl But B  Fruit 2   b     e        g       2       7  
Ctrl But C  Fruit 3   a     d        f       3      10
Ctrl But D  Fruit 4   b     e        g       4       8
```

where 'Ctrl But A' are control buttons.

When each button is pressed, I would like to output the row information in a particular format into a csv file. For example, if button A is pressed I would like to output the following:

```
Name: Fruit A
Colour: a
Shape: d
Size: f
Cost: 1
Note 1: 6
Note 2: 9
```

What is the best way to achieve this, if the table's columns are variable?

The code would do something like this:

```
1. go to the top of the 'Name' cell 
2. look up the value in the same row as the button 
3. go to the top of the 'Color' cell
4. look up the value in the same row as the button 
repeat until the end of the row is reached
output and save file
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming:

- cells underlying buttons are empty
- columns with data start right of buttons

the you can try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub FruitButton()
Dim iRow As Long, iniCol As Long, endCol As Long, jCol As Long

Open "C:\mypath\myfile.csv" For Output As #1 '<== adapt it to your needs

With ActiveSheet
    Call GetIniEndCol(.Buttons(Application.Caller), ActiveSheet, iRow, iniCol, endCol)
    For jCol = iniCol To endCol
        Write #1, .Cells(1, jCol) & ": " & .Cells(iRow, jCol)
    Next jCol
End With

Close #1

End Sub


Sub GetIniEndCol(myButton As Button, ws As Worksheet, iRow As Long, iniCol As Long, endCol As Long)
Dim iCol As Long

With myButton.TopLeftCell
    iRow = .Row
    iCol = .Column
End With

With ws
    iniCol = .Cells(iRow, iCol).End(xlToRight).Column
    endCol = .Cells(iRow, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

End Sub
```